# Какой знак препинания ставить при противопоставлении?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире, бсп

> Вместе с коллегами учёные в лаборатории в целях эксперимента поливали
>   зёрна пшеницы разной водой: одна вода слышала только ругательные
>   слова, другая вода – только положительные.

Нужно ли ставить тире вместо запятой, если перед словосочетанием `другая вода` можно вставить "а"? В каких случаях при подобном противопоставлении нужно ставить запятую, а в каких тире?

> Перед второй частью бессоюзного сложного предложения ставится тире, если в ней выражено противопоставление по отношению к содержанию первой части.

Но есть много предложений, где ставят запятую в том месте, где могло бы стоять "а".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Уберём первую часть предложения, поскольку речь идёт о второй.

***Одна вода слышала только ругательные слова, другая вода — только положительные.***

Казалось бы, на первый взгляд мы имеем дело с противоположными по значению частями бессоюзного предложения и тире вместо запятой поставить можно, особенно если произнести первую часть с повышением тона голоса на слове *ругАтельные*. Тогда ***другая вода*** окажется между тире, что на письме будет плохо восприниматься и выглядеть как вставка. Восстановить пропущенное сказуемое во второй части тоже не вариант (будет плохо читаться).

На самом деле в тире нет необходимости. Что ***одна вода***, что ***другая вода*** (кстати, можно убрать повтор слова *вода*) совершали ***одно и то же действие*** — *слышали*, только были поставлены в разные условия. Это не тот случай, где содержится резкое противопоставление частей предложения, о котором говорится в правиле, приводящем такие примеры, как:

*Не сумку у Мишки украли — последнюю надежду похитили* (Неверов); *Смелые побеждают — трусливые погибают*; *Весна сажает — осень собирает.*

В нашем предложении мы снова сталкиваемся с ***однотипно построенными частями*** сложного предложения при пропуске какого-либо члена или даже без пропуска:

*Одна вода слышала только ругательные слова, другая — только положительные [, третья — ничего не слышала, а четвёртая — говорила сама].*

P. S. Если экспериментаторы или те, кто описывают опыт, не склонны одушевлять воду, слово *слышала* нужно взять в кавычки.

Comment: А если я употребляю слово в переносном значении - это ошибка? И эти кавычка вокруг одного слова что-то страшно использовать

Comment: @askobar  Это, скорее, употребление слова в особом, необычном значении. Думаю, наоборот — к кавычкам никто не придерется, это их функция при использовании слова не по прямому его смыслу, и ничего страшного здесь не должно быть. А вот без кавычек — смотря как к этому отнесется дотошный экзаменатор.  Вот ссылка на Грамоту, но там немного информации, нужно еще глянуть. http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/53-kav1

Comment: Там написано о факультативности кавычек, но всё же, ещё раз: слово употреблено не в переносном значении, (см. Викисловарь,   https://ru.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/слышать  пункты 4, 5), а необычном, потому что относится к неодушевленному предмету. Чтобы не рисковать, я бы кавычки поставил.

Answer (score 0):

Данный  вопрос представляет интерес, но построен он **некорректно.**

Вопрос  затрагивает тему **выбора** запятой или тире при обозначении противопоставления, но в приведенном примере **выбора нет**. Там уже поставлено тире в неполном предложении, поэтому постановка второго тире вместо запятой исключена.

Соответственно,  **дать на вопрос корректный ответ не представляется возможным.**