# Как обозначить противопоставление по Розенталю?

Tags: запятые, тире, бессоюзное

Казалось бы, нет ничего проще. Надо прочитать п.2  его правил и ознакомиться с примерами. 
http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=151#pp151

Итак:
«Перед второй частью БСП ставится тире, если в ней выражено **противопоставление** по отношению к содержанию первой части (между частями можно вставить союз НО или А)».

Кстати,  здесь говорится **о  любом противопоставлении, даже не «резком».** Но сразу возникают вопрос: ведь тире ставится не всегда, **запятую тоже можно поставить.**

Вот пример из другой книги Розенталя: «**Ты богат, я очень беден**; Ты прозаик, я поэт; Ты румян как маков цвет, Я как смерть и тощ и бледен». Чем не противопоставление у нашего поэта? Кстати, тире там тоже возможно (***ты богат – я очень беден***), но это будет **усиление** противопоставления с помощью интонации, то есть **интонационное** тире.

Но **не с каждым предложением**, где есть противопоставление,  можно так поступить. Попробуем переделать пример из классики: ***Ему следовал чин за чином, а он вдруг оставил службу.***  Здесь союз А не уберешь, так что ни запятая, ни тире не подойдут  – предложение надо перестраивать. А как? Что за структура у тех, которые приведены в правилах?  Ответ-то мы знаем: ***Чин следовал ему — он службу вдруг оставил*** (Гр.);

Надо сказать, что **примеры у Розенталя разные** – всё перемешано (как говорится, тряпки с салфетками).

Можно для проверки подставить **союз А, а можно союз НО,** а ведь это разные союзы, не всегда взаимозаменяемые. Союз А сопоставительный (обозначает  различаемые или противоположные ситуации, но при этом сосуществующие), а союз НО обозначает конфликт ситуаций, взаимоисключение, ограничение и т.д.

В то же время в сопоставительных отношениях выделяют как **чистое сопоставление, так и противопоставление.** Ужас! Да еще здесь же конструкция **вида НЕ…А**, в которой тире ставится просто формально,  при пропуске союза А.

**Может,  всё это надо  учитывать при выборе конструкции?** Да и вообще это надо бы знать, чтобы правильно использовать термины при анализе (не на бытовом уровне), хотя бы как-то разбираться в этом.

Тем не менее, везде в приведенных правилах стоит тире, а **наш вопрос остается открытым**: в каких случаях при обозначении противопоставления ставится **только тире** (как в примерах Розенталя), а когда **и запятой можно обойтись**?

**В примечании,** которое приведено там же,  говорится об интонационном варианте запятой (кстати, совершенно не по теме, здесь отношения не сочинительные, а взаимообусловленные): *Человек не иголка, найдём.*

Тема связана с другим вопросом [Какой знак препинания ставить при противопоставлении?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/460676/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8)

Answer (score 1):

**Противопоставление** не всегда следует из *противоположности смыслов* двух частей предложения. Контекст (наряду с пунктуацией, интонацией и некоторыми союзами) может, по желанию автора, такое противопоставление проявить (усилить)

> У нас разные интересы. Ты богач - [, а] я бедняк.

или снять:

> Ты богач, я бедняк. А вирусу-то какая разница?

Пушкин в этом смысле "примиряет параллельные миры", вместо их *противопоставления* по пунктам, - они в результате уравновешивают и дополняют друг друга.

Comment: Alex_ander, спасибо за ответ.  Я попробую прокомментировать его чуть позже.

Answer (score 1):

**Вместо вступления**

Я  сама отвечу на  вопрос, но  ответ я посвящаю своему  **Неизвестному Читателю.** Может, он из будущего времени, а может быть, мы с ним просто незнакомы. Признаться, я мечтаю о таком читателе – благожелательном, вдумчивом, настроенном на диалог.
Я не призываю его соглашаться со своим мнением – возможно, он сделает другие выводы.  Мы просто вместе с ним прочитаем эту тему в правилах Розенталя, и возможно, он захочет  все остальные правила прочитать не формально, а так же внимательно. **Всё ли в них правильно, логично, нет ли противоречий или недосказанности?**  Можно ли улучшить текст, сделать его более понятным? И тогда будет относиться к русской письменности с большим интересом и любовью.

**Мы часто только делаем вид, что понимаем нечто,** обманывая самих себя. Мы можем даже что-то доказывать, объяснять, цитировать, но при этом наше сознание остается смутным, лишенным ясности и истинного понимания вещей.

**Ответ на вопрос**

Тема противопоставления у Розенталя изложена очень коротко. 
**Вот текст**: «Перед второй частью бессоюзного сложного предложения ставится тире, если в ней выражено противопоставление по отношению к содержанию первой части (между частями можно вставить союз НО или А)».

А дальше приведены **примеры**, вот они и представляют интерес для нашего наблюдения и изучения. Попробуем ответить на такие вопросы

**1. Можно  ли противопоставление/сопоставление в БСП обозначить не тире, а запятой?**

Вероятно, да, такие предложения встречаются. Но мы (в качестве примера) начнем наше рассуждение с союзного предложения:  ***Еще недавно Интернет был мечтой, а сегодня это реальность для миллионов***.

Сопоставление выражено союзом А, а также особой **лексикой**: *недавно – сегодня, мечта – реальность.* Союзные предложения удобны тем, что к ним не предъявляются особые требования по структуре  и распространенности предложений. (Союзом А мы можем соединить даже сложные предложения, а  не только простые).

**А можно ли здесь убрать союз и поставить запятую?** Да, можно, но тогда появляются требования **к наличию контекста**, также мы внимательно следим за интонацией в БСП: В нашей жизни всё стремительно меняется. Еще **недАвно** /Интернет был **мечтОй**,  **сегОдня** /это **реальность** для миллиОнов.

**Примечание.** Кстати, в ответе Alex_ander приводится похожий пример с контекстом,  после которого следует пояснение:  У нас разные интересы. Ты богач,  я бедняк.

И вот при постановке запятой в БСП сопоставление выражено  **только лексикой, но не интонацией.** Поэтому между предложениями не сопоставительное, а распространительное отношение:  **перед запятой голос понижается, как в конце предложения** (как будто два самостоятельных предложения разделены  короткой, а не длинной паузой). Такая интонация называется **«нисходяще-нисходящая».**

**2. А тире вместо запятой можно поставить?**

А вот это сделать  **не получится.**  Неверно думать, что антонимы можно логически подчеркнуть ударением, паузу увеличить, а на письме поставить тире. В нашем предложении с  запятой антонимы  и так уже выделены ударением, а вот **структура** этого предложения совершенно неподходящая для тире.

**Почему?**  В  БСП при постановке тире предложение **«распадается на две части»** (по Розенталю). Это значит, что каждая  часть –  это одна фонетическая фраза с одним ударением, а интонация здесь **восходяще-нисходящая**, то есть повышение голоса перед паузой, обозначенной тире.

Вообще говоря, подобные конструкции характерны для устной, народно-поэтической  и художественной речи, где нет длинных книжных фраз. **Они эмоциональны, выразительны, тем и хороши.**

Итак,  структура БСП  (при противопоставлении  и постановке тире) должна быть **особая:**  достаточно короткие предложения, в которых можно правильно расставить логические ударения.

**3.  А можно вместо тире поставить запятую?**

Представим, что мы не знаем, что там поставлено в комедии Грибоедова, и делаем выбор: ***Служить бы рад (?)прислуживаться тошно.***

Это предложение интересно тем, что к данной грамматике подходят все варианты (структура не перестраивается), но интонация разная.

**Союзный вариант** (в интонации возможны варианты):  Служить бы рад, а прислуживаться тошно.

**БСП с запятой**: СлужИть бы рАд, прислУживаться тОшно.

**БСП с тире:** Служить бы рАд – прислУживаться тошно (двухчастная конструкция, только две фразы)

Разумеется, **третий вариант наилучший**.  Это и есть настоящая русская речь, краткая и выразительная.

А вот пример, где структура предложения в заданном тексте соответствует только тире:  ***Ввысь взлетает Сокол — жмётся Уж к земле.***

Поставить союз А не получится из-за инверсии сказуемого,  а при постановке запятой получается **перечислительная** интонация, которая не соответствует нашей семантике противопоставления:  ВвЫсь взлетает /сОкол, жмётся Уж/ к землЕ.   Получается не противопоставление, а такая картинка: каждый занят своим делом.

**4. Вывод**

Так что же не так у Розенталя, если остаются вопросы?

Про двухчастные конструкции сказано в п.1, но не говорится в п.2. И конечно,  это **однозначность высказывания**: можно подумать, что тире ставится всегда.  Но мы же видим, что не всегда, а как же **выбрать**?

А вот это наш Розенталь (наше всё) **оставил нам на доработку**: думайте сами, решайте сами… Хватит с вас  и примеров.

**Спасибо тебе за внимание, мой дорогой Неизвестный Читатель.**